# is there any code editor plugin for converting jade to html?

Tags: html, pug

I'm new to *jade* so it's difficult for me to design a web page by it. i need to test the code and see the result continuously.

i want to know is there any way to convert jade to html and viceversa in code editor?
is there any plugin? No matter what code editor but if there is sublime plugin it is better for me.

Comment: did you find a way to convert html to jade within sublimetext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a dedicated [Node](http://nodejs.org) + [Express](http://expressjs.com) app with a single view and paste in your [jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) and check it in a browser.

Jade Syntax Documentation with interactive samples:

http://naltatis.github.com/jade-syntax-docs/

There is a "Jade" package for [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) available using package control. When combined with a decent colour scheme, syntax errors are very obvious.

ST2 package control:

http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control

The current "Jade" bundle / package:

https://github.com/davidrios/jade-tmbundle

Package control's known repositories:

https://github.com/wbond/package_control_channel/blob/master/repositories.json

Online html to jade converters:

http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/

http://www.htmltojade.com/

Answer (score 0):

jade itself transforms jade files to html automatically. But keep in mind that jade is a templating language with interpreted commands and thus is not a one to one conversion from jade to html.

BTW, there's a tool that do html to jade conversion available here : https://github.com/donpark/html2jade

Probably you can run them from SublimeText

Answer (score 0):

Check [prepros from alphapixels](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/). It compiles jade, haml, sass / scss, less and coffee. It watches your file for changes and compiles on real-time, so **you can use the code editor of your choice**. It works fine for me.